# 'data-rel' lightbox not working with ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this piece of code which is a partial for a one page website and i call it with ajax to fill the 'portfolio content' of the website.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="heading-section col-md-12 text-center">
            <h2>{{ $data['generals']->portfolio_title }}</h2>
            <p>{{ $data['generals']->portfolio_secondary_title }}</p>
        </div> <!-- /.heading-section -->
    </div> <!-- /.row -->
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($data['portfolio'] as $port)
        <div class="portfolio-item col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="portfolio-thumb">
                <img src="visitor/images/gallery/{{$port->background_image}}" alt="">
                <div class="portfolio-overlay">
                    <h3>{{$port->title}}</h3>
                    <p>{{$port->body}}</p>
                    <a href="visitor/images/gallery/{{$port->background_image}}" data-rel="lightbox" class="expand">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </a>
                </div> <!-- /.portfolio-overlay -->
            </div> <!-- /.portfolio-thumb -->
        </div> <!-- /.portfolio-item -->
        @endforeach
    </div> <!-- /.row -->
</div> <!-- /.container -->
```

When i call it with ajax the `data-rel="lightbox"` is not working. If i don't call it and i just include the code in the project it is working just fine. Why AJAX won't let it work?

I call it like this:

```
function appendData(div, url){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            $(div).append(data);
        }
    });
}
appendData('#portfolio');
```

I am using this [plugin](https://github.com/duncanmcdougall/Responsive-Lightbox)

And I call it like this :

```
  $(function(){
    $('[data-rel="lightbox"]').lightbox();
  });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to initialize the plugin after adding the new DOM to the document :

```
function appendData(div, url){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
             $(div).append(data);

             $('[data-rel="lightbox"]').lightBox(); //init plugin for new elements
        }
    });
}
```

**NOTE :** You should initialize your plugin inside `success` callback where the new elements are already appended to the DOM, it will not work if you call it after `appendData` since `$.ajax` request is asynchronous.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Give us the exact lightBox plugin that you're using please.

Comment: How you init your plugin? are you using `.lightBox();` anywhere else.

Comment: Actually yes i do. I just saw it. Sorry i just have a template where i exercise for back end mostly and i didn't know it. The author of the template calls it as you said

Comment: without the 'a'

Comment: ok try to add it without 'a' just after `$(div).append(data);`.. check my update.

Comment: I did but still won't work! I also erased it from where the author had it and put it after the append but same thing happens

Comment: i am getting somewhere i will let you know in a few minutes

Comment: Ok it is working. I just didn't checked your last update. I had some more issues because i calle the appendData more tha once but i fixed it. Thanks! :)) If you want add to your answer why i cant call it under the 'appendData('#portfolio');' and i have to call it inside